# Putting data from a column of one table into column of another depending on value

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel like this should be rather simple but for some reason I can't quite make sense of this issue.

In my query below, I'm simply joining some tables and putting data from each into one small/concise table. However, it runs into an issue at the first line with `LEGTYPE1` and it says `the FUNCTION a.LEGTYPE1 does not exist`.

`LEGTYPE1` is a column in the 'a' table that houses either a 1 or a 2, and I need it to enter a '1' in the inbound column if it's a 1 and ANSWERED = 1 and a 2 in the outbound column if the value is a '2'.

I have a similar query in another table that does the same thing except it gets a sum of all LEGTYPE values of 1 and 2 and it works fine but I think it's because I'm using a sum and this is just meant to put the value itself.

Here's the query:

```
Insert into test.AMBrawDataDump(
            Extension, 
            Start_Time,
            End_Time,
            Duration, 
            Inbound_Answered, 
            Missed, 
            Outbound, 
            Hold_Time)  
SELECT 
              c.extension -- USER EXTENSION
            , b.STARTTIME -- Start of call
            , b.ENDTIME   -- End of call
            , b.DURATION  -- Length of call
            , LEGTYPE1(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1)  -- Inbound answered calls
            , b.ANSWERED(if(Answered = 1,0,1))                   -- Missed Calls
            , a.LEGTYPE1(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0))                 -- Outbound calls
            , a.HOLDTIMESECS                                     -- Hold time in seconds
FROM cdrdb.session a
INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
 ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
 ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
 WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 90 day and curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
ORDER BY c.extension, DATE(b.ts);
```

EXAMPLE DATA:

[image]

This is what I get if I just put the LEGTYPE values in, but I want it to only fill the Inbound column if it's 2 and outbound column if it's 1.

In the session table, LEGTYPE1 is a smallint column.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected results for both tables?

Comment: Updated with an image of data and an explanation if that helps

Comment: Was that more what you were looking for?

Comment: You already tagged the answer below as correct. This inquiry is already closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are trying to get the return value of the IF function and name it LEGTYPE1, correct?

The reason your current solution is not working is that you are using LEGTYPE1 as a function, when it is in fact a field.

You could, instead, do something like this :

```
CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS YourFieldNameHere
```

Comment: I ran this but it's still putting the value from the source table (1,2) rather than 0 or 1 like the CASE states

Comment: could you provide me with a code snippet of your most recent changes?